# How can i use bootstrap js library in my theme?

Tags: javascript

I use bootstrap drupal theme. And i want to use collapse.

I added in theme.info the library path bootstrap.js have cleaned the cache, but after using the following code generates only the button, but the content is not deployed.

```
      <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
```

Most likely is not initializing bootsrap.js, please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: I just ran this [example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript#collapse-example) with no problem inside a body text field. I have [bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) installed, loading bootstrap files from CDN, and did not have to add bootstrap.js at all. Inspect your browser console for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i fixed this problem by using jQuery with more higher version.